# Getting direction from google API

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

I´m currently working on an app where users can record a route on a map using Google maps APIv.2. This route will be the guide-route for another user. Same when you request a route from one point to another on a GPS or google maps. The GPS then tells you to take left in 200 meters etc. How can I get this value from the API? 
Which determines whether the next turn is a road-cross or just a 90 degree turn.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Google API provides various map in many platform.I think using js for android is better than native.Here is newest api it allows gps coordination and distance etc
[Link is here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/)